# hook_nodeapi() - How to order additional fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I used hook_nodeapi to add my custom field to a type of node

```
$node->content['my_new_field'] = array(
  '#value' => $content,
);
```

However the new field is only appeared at the end of the content. Is there anyway for me to select a place for it to display ? e.g: between Title and Body.

For some reason I won't be able to use CCK, I want to do it programmatically.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something called `weight`. If you llok at the code from [API docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi/6), you'll see how that is supposed to work. Lower numbers appear before higher numbers.

So you could do something like

```
$node->content['my_new_field'] = array(
   '#value' => $content,
   '#weight' => 5, //play with the values until you are happy with the output
 );
```

Comment: If you implement CCK's hook_content_extra_fields() you will be able to use CCK's drag-n-drop reordering to override the weight specified here. It's a good trick if you are also using CCK fields for other stuff.

Comment: Sounds like hes not using CCK though

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you implement hook_load instead to append the node object with your custom fields:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_load/6

Then you could theme it however you want in node-customtype.tpl.php. Just a thought.

Comment: That requires too much works for me I think... I don't want to add a new template just to re-order the field